# Black screen when swiping "after" with UIPageViewController subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I tried looking for my answer in existing questions where people faced the same problem, but the solutions for those are things I already address. Here's my code:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let onboardingCoordinator = OnboardingViewCoordinator()
        let onboardingPageViewController = WarmPushPageViewController(coordinator: onboardingCoordinator)
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        guard let window = self.window else { return false }
        window.rootViewController = onboardingPageViewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
}
```

Your typical App Delegate, tried to keep it as small as possible.

**Coordinator.swift**

```
import UIKit

enum PageViewDirection {
    case before
    case after
}

typealias Index = Int

protocol PageViewCoordinator: class {
    var currentIndex: Index { get set }
    var viewControllers: [UIViewController] { get set }
    func present(direction: PageViewDirection) -> UIViewController?
}
```

**OnboardingViewCoordinator.swift**

```
import UIKit

final class OnboardingViewCoordinator: PageViewCoordinator {
    var currentIndex: Index
    var viewControllers: [UIViewController]

    init() {
        self.viewControllers = [
            OnboardingTaglineViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil),
            OnboardingSourcesViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        ]
        self.currentIndex = 0
    }

    func present(direction: PageViewDirection) -> UIViewController? {
        switch direction {
        case .before:
            if self.currentIndex == 0 {
                return nil
            }
            self.currentIndex -= 1
            let beforeVC = self.viewControllers[self.currentIndex]
            return beforeVC
        case .after:
            if self.currentIndex == (self.viewControllers.count - 1) {
                return nil
            }
            self.currentIndex += 1
            let afterVC = self.viewControllers[self.currentIndex]
            return afterVC
        }
    }
}
```

**WarmPushPageViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class WarmPushPageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    var coordinator: PageViewCoordinator? = nil

    convenience init(coordinator: PageViewCoordinator) {
        self.init(transitionStyle: .scroll,
                  navigationOrientation: .horizontal,
                  options: nil)
        self.setViewControllers([coordinator.viewControllers[coordinator.currentIndex]],
                                direction: .forward,
                                animated: true,
                                completion: nil)
        self.coordinator = coordinator
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension WarmPushPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let coordinator = self.coordinator else { return nil }
        guard let beforeVC = coordinator.present(direction: .before) else { return nil }
        return beforeVC
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let coordinator = self.coordinator else { return nil }
        guard let afterVC = coordinator.present(direction: .after) else { return nil }
        return afterVC
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Kiren :)

Comment: It sounds like this problem might have nothing to do with any of the code you’ve shown, but means merely that your view controller fails to find its view. Can you post a minimal project that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @matt https://github.com/warmpush/iOS/tree/redesign, made the repo public for now :) feel free to take a look!

Comment: I'd rather see something minimal, really. If the problem is real, it can be minimally reproduced. I can't reproduce it based on what you've said, so I assume the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: @matt Very interesting, thanks for your feedback! I'll make a minimal version of this app and send that to you in order to try and reproduce